# Subdomain doesn't redirect correctly when using HTTPS

Tags: subdomain, apache2

When using a sub domain it redirects to my default page/domain. This only happens when using HTTPS.. for example

`https://forums.example.net` - takes me to example.net ...BUT
`http://bans.example.net` - takes me to the bans website (the correct site)

I'm using Apache 2 & Ubuntu 18.04 using my own VPS. ((I also have 2 more sub domains registered to the domain but i think it may be a problem with one of my Apache configs!)) or a Cloudflare problem.

### SITES ENABLED CONFIG

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =bans.example.net [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =status.example.net [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.net [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =forums.example.net
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.net/
    ServerName example.net

    <Directory /var/www/html/example.net/>
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews +Includes
        AllowOverride FileInfo Options
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.net
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/bans.example.net/
    ServerName bans.example.net

    <Directory /var/www/html/bans.example.net/>
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews +Includes
        AllowOverride FileInfo Options
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.net [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =bans.example.net [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =forums.example.net
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

### SSL CONFIG INSIDE THE SITES-ENABLED

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.net/
    ServerName example.net

    <Directory /var/www/html/example.net/>
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews +Includes
        AllowOverride FileInfo Options
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>


Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
ServerAlias forums.example.net
ServerAlias bans.example.net
ServerAlias status.example.net
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/bans.example.net-0001/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/bans.example.net-0001/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/forums.example.net/
    ServerName forums.example.net

    <Directory /var/www/html/forums.example.net/>
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews +Includes
        AllowOverride FileInfo Options
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>


</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/bans.example.net/
    ServerName bans.example.net

    <Directory /var/www/html/bans.example.net/>
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews +Includes
        AllowOverride FileInfo Options
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>


</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =bans.example.net [OR]
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =status.example.net [OR]
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.net [OR]
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =forums.example.net
> RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
> ```

Change `SERVER_NAME` to `HTTP_HOST`. Or, look for `UseCanonicalName On` in your server config and change this directive to `Off`.

When `UseCanonicalName On` is set then the `SERVER_NAME` server variable contains the hostname from the `ServerName` directive, otherwise, it is the same as `HTTP_HOST`, ie. the hostname from the HTTP request.

If you are inside a vHost then you probably don't need to check for the requested hostname? You may not even need to use mod_rewrite here at all - a simple mod_alias `Redirect` may suffice.

However, there are other inconsistencies in your server config... (Maybe some of this is due to over exemplification?!)

- Your first code block is seemingly chopped in the middle of a vHost container?
- You have multiple vHost configs for the same port and server name. Only one can win. One has the redirect logic; the other doesn't?
- You are checking for requested hosts that are seemingly impossible? eg. in the `bans.example.net:80` vHost, the redirect is also checking against `example.net` and `forums.example.net`?
- You are wrapping vHost:80 in `<IfModule mod_ssl.c>`?